# insert into a table from another table when a new record is inserted

Tags: python, sql

I have 2 tables, I want to insert all records from the first table into the second one if the records do not exist. If a new row is added to the first table, it must be inserted into the seccond one.

I found this query
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2)
but if a new row is added to table1, the row is not inserted into table2.

PS: table1 and table2 have the same fields and contain thousands of records

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this in Python? Because this looks like a job for a trigger in MySQL/PostgreSQL/...

Comment: I am using python to connect to databases, the problem is that I don't know the query that will do this. I found this solution: 'insert into Table2 select * from table1 where not exists (select * from Table2)', but if a new record is added to the table1, it is not inserted in table2. !!!

Comment: What SQL database are you using? Afaik triggers are not standard SQL so it depends on your database system whether it **can** be done.

Comment: I am using access database

Comment: look into Triggers.

Comment: I think I can't use triggers while I am using access database !!! help !

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all in SQL - if you can run, for example, a batch every 2 minutes ...

```
-- with these two tables and their contents ...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableA;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA(id,name,dob) AS (
          SELECT 42,'Arthur Dent',DATE '1957-04-22'
UNION ALL SELECT 43,'Ford Prefect',DATE '1900-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 44,'Tricia McMillan',DATE '1959-03-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 45,'Zaphod Beeblebrox',DATE '1900-02-01'
);
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT pk_A PRIMARY KEY(id);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableB;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableB(id,name,dob) AS (
          SELECT 43,'Ford Prefect',DATE '1900-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 44,'Tricia McMillan',DATE '1959-03-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 45,'Zaphod Beeblebrox',DATE '1900-02-01'
);
ALTER TABLE tableB ADD CONSTRAINT pk_B PRIMARY KEY(id);

-- .. this MERGE statement will ad the row with id=42 to table B ..

MERGE
INTO tableB t
USING tableA s
 ON s.id   = t.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
  id
, name
, dob
) VALUES (
  s.id
, s.name
, s.dob
);
```

Comment: This is not a trigger. The OP already mentioned to copy the content of table1 to table2. The problem is they want a trigger: something that pro-actively each time a row is added to table1, also adds that row to table2.

Comment: The original question asker did not mention a trigger. And "insert all records from the first table into the second one if the records do not exist" actually leads me away from a trigger. Let's wait for what the question asker says....

Comment: The last line of the question is "*If a new row is added to the first table, it must be inserted into the seccond one.*". How can you not interpret this as a trigger?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I want something that each time a row is added to table also adds that row o table2. I have no idea what trigger is !!

Comment: Your turn, Willem

Comment: Hi kh.b. A trigger works in some databases - not all. It's a database object that initiates an action when a defined event happens against a defined table: insert, update, delete. It initiates a data manipulation action against one or more tables following that event and with the data coming from the row concerned. If the database supports it, it's useful - when you have single row insert/update-s. I would not use it in case of mass inserts. And if the database does not support it, I'd try my solution every few minutes.

Comment: I did some research nd I think I can't use triggers while I am using access database !!! help !

Answer (score 0):

So it's an Access database.

Tough luck. They have no triggers.

Well then. I suppose you know how to insert a row into Access using Python, so I won't go through that.

I'll just build a scenario just after having inserted a row.

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
  id   INTEGER
, name VARCHAR(20)
, dob  DATE
, PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)
;
INSERT INTO tableA(id,name,dob) VALUES(42,'Arthur Dent','1957-04-22');
INSERT INTO tableA(id,name,dob) VALUES(43,'Ford Prefect','1900-08-01');
INSERT INTO tableA(id,name,dob) VALUES(44,'Tricia McMillan','1959-03-07');
INSERT INTO tableA(id,name,dob) VALUES(45,'Zaphod Beeblebrox','1900-02-01');

CREATE TABLE tableB (
  id   INTEGER
, name VARCHAR(20)
, dob  DATE
, PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)
;
INSERT INTO tableB(id,name,dob) VALUES(43,'Ford Prefect','1900-08-01');
INSERT INTO tableB(id,name,dob) VALUES(44,'Tricia McMillan','1959-03-07');
INSERT INTO tableB(id,name,dob) VALUES(45,'Zaphod Beeblebrox','1900-02-01');
```

Ok. Scenario ready.

Merge ....

```
MERGE
INTO tableB t
USING tableA s
 ON s.id   = t.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
  id
, name
, dob
) VALUES (
  s.id
, s.name
, s.dob
);

42000:1:-3500:[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 
Invalid SQL statement; 
expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.
```

So, Merge not supported.

Trying something else:

```
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE id <> ALL (SELECT id FROM tableB)
;

1 row inserted
```

Or:

```
-- UNDO the previous insert
DELETE FROM tableB WHERE id=42;
1 row deleted
-- retry ...
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tableB)
;
1 row inserted
```

You could run it like here above.

Or, if your insert into Table A, from Python, was:

```
INSERT INTO tableA(id,name,dob) VALUES(?,?,?);
```

... and you supplied the values for id, name and dob via host variables,
you could continue with:

```
INSERT INTO tableB 
SELECT * FROM tableA a 
WHERE id=? 
  AND NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE id=a.id
  );
```

You would still have the value 42 in the first host variable, and could just reuse it. It would be faster this way in case of single row inserts.

Should you perform mass inserts, then, I would insert all new rows to table A, then run the `INSERT ... WHERE ... NOT IN` or the `INSERT ... WHERE id <> ALL ....` .